# idiom for getting contiguous copies

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

In the help of numpy.broadcst-array, an idiom is introduced.
However, the idiom give exactly the same output as original command.
Waht is the meaning of "getting contiguous copies instead of non-contiguous views."?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
y = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])]
```

Here is a useful idiom for getting contiguous copies instead of non-contiguous views.

```
[np.array(a) for a in np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)]

[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the difference try writing into the new arrays:

Let's begin with the contiguous copies.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3]])
>>> y = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
>>> 
>>> xc, yc = [np.array(a) for a in np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)]
>>> xc
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

We can modify an element and nothing unexpected will happen.

```
>>> xc[0, 0] = 0
>>> xc
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],                                                                                                   
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Now, let's try the same with the broadcasted arrays:

```
>>> xb, yb = np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)
>>> xb
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Although we only write to the top left element ...

```
>>> xb[0, 0] = 0
```

... the entire left column will change ...

```
>>> xb
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

... and also the input array.

```
>>> x
array([[0, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that `broadcast_arrays` function doesn't create entirely new object. It creates views from original arrays which means the elements of it's results have memory addresses as those arrays which may or may not be contiguous. But when you create a list you're creating new copies within a list which guarantees that its items are stored contiguous in memory.

You can check this like following:

```
arr = np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)
In [144]: arr
Out[144]: 
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]])]

In [145]: x
Out[145]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [146]: arr[0][0] = 0

In [147]: arr
Out[147]: 
[array([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]])]

In [148]: x
Out[148]: array([[0, 0, 0]])
```

As you can see, changing the `arr`'s elements is changing both its elements and the original `x` array.